# Is there an equivallent to a jsFiddle for ASP.NET / VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jsfiddle

Is there anything out there that can do what jsFiddle does, but for asp.net things, like code I have in Visual Studio (vb)?  Something where you can plug in your code, see the result, and perhaps save it so another coder can look at it and debug it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

.NET Fiddle supports [ASP.NET MVC](http://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc)(thanks, @Eric) with both C# and VB.NET. Also there are several that either for ASP.NET(but C#) or VB.NET(but console or WinForms):

- [.NET Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/) - supports VB.NET (ASP.NET MVC and console)
- [CodeRun Studio](http://coderun.com/) - supports ASP.NET but with C#.
- [Compilr](http://compilr.com/) - supports VB.NET (but only for console or Winform apps)
- [ideone](http://ideone.com/) - online compiler and debugger; supports VB.NET (but don't think you'll be able to run ASP.NET there)

Comment: Thank you for the links, Alex.  I'll definitely check 'em out.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: .NET Fiddle now also support ASP.NET MVC with C# and VB.NET http://dotnetfiddle.net/CsMvc

Answer (score 1):

A .NET Fiddle (for the C# language) is https://compilify.net/

Answer (score 0):

For VBScript or ASP Classic, or for modeling VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) such as macros used in Microsoft Excel (but without specific Excel libraries), there is:

http://VBFiddle.net

I developed this website/script a few weeks ago specifically as a Thank you! to all of the contributors of Stack Exchange, Stack Overflow, and all of their universe of sites, and I find it very useful for quick prototyping or to show someone my VBScript code... for example with VBScript's RegEx engine which has some quirks specific to VBScript.

VBFiddle.net does not yet support saving your VBScript on the website, but you can save your VBScript to say jSFiddle.net and link to that, and instruct people to copy and paste into http://VBFiddle.net. I will add saving support to VB Fiddle / Visual Basic Classic Fiddle if there is enough interest.

Enjoy!