# JSFIDDLE not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, jquery-ui

Using custom built package from JQuery UI 1.10.3 in my project,

```
 <link href="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/css/start/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I copied the js and css files to gist where I then used RawGit to get a URL to include as an external resource to try and recreate what is happening in my project in a JSFIDDLE.

Problem, being I cant get the JSFIDDLE working does anyone know why....when user clicks on 'create New Layer' button a popUp should appear holding 3 radio buttons with images 'new layer','import layer','external data', select which option the user wants and click next.

Although I cant get the popUp to appear in JSFIDDLE here is where I am at.....any help appreciated:
https://jsfiddle.net/j73vpk1m/7/

Just a thought...the two files are .css and .js, when i used RawGit then both out putted 2 js files...possible problem?

Comment: The function `InvokeCreateLayerOption()` on line of code `<input type="button" class="edit green btn" id="buttonCreateLayer" onclick="InvokeCreateLayerOption();" value="Create New Layer" style="float:right;"/> ` has not been defined. Please review your code again.

Comment: That's not correct @AhsN, it is defined in the js panel.

Comment: 1. You jsfiddle use `onload` at `Framework & Extension` part, which wrap the function you defined in `script` part in a onload function, thus make them unreachable to button => change `onload` to `no wrap - in <head>`.

Comment: 2. You should take a look to `7eae9ae5ed977bcf943c.js` and another in `External Res` bar, click it and see what it looks like... It just not a valid js file you import.

Comment: @3abqari The console was throwing this error. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3):

jsfiddle doesn't accept asp.net controls.  You're using some asp.net controls like `<asp:UpdatePanel>` and `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>`.  You can use only HTML controls in your HTML panel in jsfiddle.

Here is a question that might answer your next question of where can I fiddle with asp.net code: [Is there an equivallent to a jsFiddle for ASP.NET / VB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9108025/is-there-an-equivallent-to-a-jsfiddle-for-asp-net-vb)

Comment: I'd upvote this for preventing another question in this series!